# Dynamic graph out of realtime data in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I have a pandas dataframe (`total_df`) that combines a static dataframe (`df0`) with a dataframe (`reduced_rdf`) created out of realtime dictionaries (`d1`). The code is:

```
rdf = pd.DataFrame()
while True:
  for D in (d1):
    rdf1 = pd.DataFrame(d1).T
    reduced_rdf = rdf1[["from", "close", "min", "max", "volume"]]
    rdf = pd.concat([rdf, reduced_rdf], ignore_index=True)
    total_df = pd.concat([df0, rdf], ignore_index=True)
  time.sleep(1)
  print(total_df)
```

However, the output involves several dataframes (each one with one more row):

```
             id        from            at  ...      min      max volume
0     1159393.0  1607434980  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21151  1.21217    287
1     1159394.0  1607435040  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21175  1.21193    196
2     1159395.0  1607435100  1.607435e+18  ...   1.2117  1.21188    138
3     1159396.0  1607435160  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21132  1.21187    177
4     1159397.0  1607435220  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21127  1.21153    181
...         ...         ...           ...  ...      ...      ...    ...
1996  1161389.0  1607554740  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20806  1.20808      8
1997  1161390.0  1607554800  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20803  1.20818     84
1998  1161391.0  1607554860  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20787  1.20807     74
1999  1161392.0  1607554920  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20778  1.20787     52
2000        NaN  1607560260           NaN  ...  1.20819  1.20829     35

[2001 rows x 9 columns]
             id        from            at  ...      min      max volume
0     1159393.0  1607434980  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21151  1.21217    287
1     1159394.0  1607435040  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21175  1.21193    196
2     1159395.0  1607435100  1.607435e+18  ...   1.2117  1.21188    138
3     1159396.0  1607435160  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21132  1.21187    177
4     1159397.0  1607435220  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21127  1.21153    181
...         ...         ...           ...  ...      ...      ...    ...
1997  1161390.0  1607554800  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20803  1.20818     84
1998  1161391.0  1607554860  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20787  1.20807     74
1999  1161392.0  1607554920  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20778  1.20787     52
2000        NaN  1607560260           NaN  ...  1.20819  1.20829     35
2001        NaN  1607560260           NaN  ...  1.20819  1.20829     36

[2002 rows x 9 columns]
             id        from            at  ...      min      max volume
0     1159393.0  1607434980  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21151  1.21217    287
1     1159394.0  1607435040  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21175  1.21193    196
2     1159395.0  1607435100  1.607435e+18  ...   1.2117  1.21188    138
3     1159396.0  1607435160  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21132  1.21187    177
4     1159397.0  1607435220  1.607435e+18  ...  1.21127  1.21153    181
...         ...         ...           ...  ...      ...      ...    ...
1998  1161391.0  1607554860  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20787  1.20807     74
1999  1161392.0  1607554920  1.607555e+18  ...  1.20778  1.20787     52
2000        NaN  1607560260           NaN  ...  1.20819  1.20829     35
2001        NaN  1607560260           NaN  ...  1.20819  1.20829     36
2002        NaN  1607560260           NaN  ...  1.20819  1.20829     36

[2003 rows x 9 columns]
```

My first question is: is there any way to just add one row each time to a single dataframe instead of printing dataframes over and over? Ok, now my second question, how can I create a dynamic graph out of this real-time data? I tried using FuncAnimation function from matplotlib, but I don't know how to integrate that code into the one that I already have. I appreciate your help, thank you.